# NativeScript ListView image render

Tags: listview, scroll, scrollview, render, nativescript

I am new in NativeScript and trying to figure out how to render images with fade/opacity effect. I have ListView with items which includes text and image on the side. When I scroll up and down, images get loaded all over again. They actually render again each time they are displayed. I would like to animate that if possible. `loaded="slikaUcitana"` is called on each image load, but that does not work when I scroll up and down.

**Here is my view:**

```
<ListView.itemTemplate>
<StackLayout>

 <GridLayout columns="auto, *" route="browse/browse-page" title="Browse" itemTap="onNavigationItemTap">
   <Image row="0" col="0" loaded="slikaUcitana" class="lista-artikli-slika" id="slicice" opacity="0" stretch="aspectFit" src="{{ 'http://www.mydomain_IMAGE_LOCATION/' + slika_image }}" />
  </GridLayout>


 </StackLayout>
</ListView.itemTemplate>
```

**And here is JavaScript code:**

```
function slikaUcitana(args){
    var page = args.object;
    console.log('slika je ucitana, argumenti: ', page);
    page.getViewById("slicice").animate({
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 1000 
      });

}
exports.slikaUcitana = slikaUcitana;
```

Is there any plugin for image rendering on scroll?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue before. You should not animate the image from component (though you can). I would advise to use css. For reloading image, you need to cache the image and that you can achieve it using [ImageCache](https://github.com/VideoSpike/nativescript-web-image-cache) plugin. For css animation, check [Animate.css](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-animatecss) plugin or copy the fadeIn animation code from there.